# HelpSpot to Fogbugz to HelpSpot integration

Tags: integration, fogbugz

Does anyone have a nice example of integration between HelpSpot and Fogbugz?

We're using HelpSpot as our customer facing software and ticket management, and then if a developer needs to work on a ticket the data will be pushed to Fogbugz.

Obviously we can use the Fogbugz push API that Userscape provides, but this only allows you to specify the title of the incident in Fogbugz. Ideally I want to share title, assigned to, category and status in a two-way integration.

Do most people just use emails between the two programs, or has anyone come across a nice third party app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might get better help with this on the dedicated [FogBugz StackExchange](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/) website.

Answer (score 1):

The FogBugz API example in the [HelpSpot](http://www.helpspot.com) docs can be modified to do what you want. What you can do is specify you're own format for the push box text. So have staff put the category on line one, a note on line 2, etc and then parse it in the FB push file and set it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

For the HelpSpot --> FogBugz way: as far as I can see, the provided FogBugz push implementation is only an example which you can extend and customize to your needs.

If you look at the `push` function in RequestPush-FogBugz.php there are the parameters sending to FogBugz. You can set additional data in here (request attributes are specified in the [HelpSpot documentation](http://www.helpspot.com/helpdesk/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=156) and FogBugz fields are specified in the [FogBugz API documentation](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/70/topics/advanced/API.html)).

Of course you have to provide the mapping between users and other metadata (or e.g. use the exactly same usernames in FogBugz and HelpSpot).